# Iterate through datatable progressively slower on Azure

Tags: c#, performance, loops, datatable

I've got a c# problem where we load around 10 000 rows in a data table, and then loop through them to change some data.

Problem is that it gets progressively slower as it goes through the loop.  Every iteration is a few milliseconds slower, up to a point where it is v e r y slow.

But before you ask for code or give work arounds to my existing coding, here is what is interesting: it only happens on Azure.  And not all Azure servers, only on 1, maybe 2.  The exact same config, db, and data on a different server does not have the same problem.

Are anyone aware of something in Azure or Win 2012 R2 that might cause such behavior?

EDIT:

Quite interesting is that the problem seems to have nothing to do with what is in the loop.  This loop now just prints snapshots to screen.  First 100 rows take 6 seconds.  40th set takes 40 seconds, and going slower.  Here is the simplified code.

```
   var format = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter(); 
    var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    var ds = format.Deserialize(fs) as DataSet; 
    fs.Close();

    System.Data.DataTable table = ds.tables[0]; 
    table.Columns.Add("TEMP", typeof(string));
    DateTime lastSnap = DateTime.Now; 
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 100 == 0) 
        {       
            PrintToScreen((DateTime.Now - lastSnap).Seconds);           
            lastSnap = DateTime.Now;    
        }  
    }
```

Comment: If you -1 at least tell us why please.

Comment: Sorry, but without any code inside your loop it's unlikely you get an answer. And commenting on -1 is explicitly prohibited in SO rules. You should have posted your code anyway, because it could be a trivial algorithmic complexity issue, but this way others just have no chance to guess.

Comment: OK - thanks.  If it was a logical error then it should happen on all servers.  If it is 1 server in 20, then I don't think the coding is the main cause.  The reason I did not put code is to prevent people from giving alternative coding, as it will solve the cause but not the underlying problem.  IMHO anyway.

Comment: If it's infrastructure related, you should show the functions you use to access and update your data to find out which might cause the problem. But i'm pretty sure it's an algorithmic complexity bug. Here is a trivial example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RIzZq1 Try to increase the number by 10 and you will understand.

Comment: The infrastructure and configuration could only contribute to trigger such a behaviour by altering some data involved in the computation, but i'm pretty sure azure as well as any other db technology is not subject to algorithmic complexity bugs by itself.

Comment: So it's the PrintToScreen part which get's slower. Please post the PrintToScreen code.

Comment: Try also measuring the loop with a Stopwatch rather than the TimeSpan arithmetic, see if the output still behaves similar.

Comment: How is the question related to Azure? The code simply iterates over an in-memory datatable. And doesn't even measure the elapsed time, just the timespan's seconds value.

Comment: It relates to Azure in the sense that we only get the degrading time performance on an Azure box, and not on any other VM that we've tested on.  It MAY be Azure as that is the only difference that we know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as suspected, it does not have anything to do with the logic.  For some or other reason the exe was running in Windows 8 compatibility mode.
Removing that flag solved the problem.